# consuming web service - Local endpoint XXX does not exist

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I have created a AIF- document service frame work in AX.

When I consume the service in C# using WSDL, I can't able to consume, I am getting a exception.

when I saw the exception in Exception form in AX 2009, I got the following error.

"Local endpoint 'XXX' does not exist".

Any Idea regarding this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know much about dynamics, but when I test wcf I use wcftestclient.
Have you tried consuming the service with that?

Comment: Hi skalpin..I have tested this by creating a sample console C# application. I will check it with wcftestclient now

Comment: [Same question](http://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/p/202487/524376) in AX Community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to create an entry in the form

`Basic -> Setup -> Application Integration Framework -> Local endpoints`

with the value 'XXX' pointing to the actual company you are targeting so that the web service call 'knows' in which company the code should be executed.